# Python-Replace rows in a column using condition in other column using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
A    B
abc  AN 
abd  BN
a01  CN
abc  BN
a02  CN
```

I have a dataframe similar to above. For every `B=CN`,I want to replace corresponding row in A i.e `a01`,`a02` with value from dictionary.
The dictionary is as follow:

```
d={'a01':'ana','a02':'aza'}
```

Whenever I'm trying to replace the values, it's giving incorrect result either the values are misplaced. I tried where clause as well but still missing something.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, specifically can you give more details about the "dataframe": is it a text file, array or some sort of data-structure? Maybe provide some existing code, MWE.

Comment: @EmilVatai There is a csv file with above dataframe.A and B are column of object type.I've to replace few values in rows of column A i.e a01 and a02 with values in dictionary d but the condition is only if B is equal to CN.

Comment: pandas.DataFrame? That part of your question is very vague... You want to change the csv or the datastructure? Could you provide a MVE?

Comment: X=pd.read_csv('somefile.csv). A and B are columns in X.I've to replace few rows in A which  have values a01 and a02 but only if the values in column B is BN.I've created a dictionary d whose value are to be used for replacing rows in A.For example: a01 should be replaced by ana only if rows in B have value equal to CN .Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single line in would look like this:

```
df.loc[df['B'].eq('CN'), 'A'] = df['A'].map(d)
df
     A   B
0  abc  AN
1  abd  BN
2  ana  CN
3  abc  BN
4  aza  CN
```

Also you can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['B'].eq('CN'), df['A'].map(d), df['A'])
```

Here is the whole code with `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abc', 'abd', 'a01', 'abc', 'a02'],
                   'B': ['AN', 'BN', 'CN', 'BN', 'CN']})

d = {'a01': 'ana', 'a02': 'aza'}

df['A'] = np.where(df['B'].eq('CN'), df['A'].map(d), df['A'])

df

     A   B
0  abc  AN
1  abd  BN
2  ana  CN
3  abc  BN
4  aza  CN
```

Comment: 0n applying it,I get 'nan' for replaced values in A.

Comment: @VroJ I've added code for your example and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to use the dictionary for mapping the values and `loc` to assign the values to the particular slice:

```
CN = df['B'] == 'CN'
df['A'].loc[CN] = df[CN].A.map(d)
df

    A   B
0   abc AN
1   abd BN
2   ana CN
3   abc BN
4   aza CN
```

Comment: 0n applying it,I get 'nan' for replaced values in A.There is a warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame".